# gem update --system returns "no implicit conversion of nil into String"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Running gem update --system keeps returning error

```
# gem update --system
    Updating rubygems-update
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

How to fix it? 
Verbose: http://pastebin.com/2uBYEMTi

Comment: Post the gem repo that is getting the problem into here http://mxtoolbox.com/SRVLookup.aspx and post your results. Is this a local machine or a VM using vagrant or docker or what? Other info for the machine and Ruby version would be helpful. Why are you updating rubygems?

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to incompatible gem versions (Maybe a gem doing Monkey patching?). Can you try to update a single gem?